# Why doesn't the new parameter work in trigger function in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to create a trigger function to check if a field value is present at another table's field. I'm using a trigger function which raises an exception when the value is not present at the other table's field. The trigger function uses the new parameter and a local variable, but instead of it working properly, it always raises my exception.

This is the code I'm running:

```
CREATE TABLE magazine (
    title VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
    author VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE pricing (
    title VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    period INT NOT NULL,
    price INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (title, period)
);

create function check_magazine_pricing_title_relation_on_magazine() returns trigger as $$
declare 
    pricings_amount integer;
Begin
    SELECT COUNT(title) FROM pricing into pricings_amount WHERE title=NEW.title;
    if (pricings_amount = 0) then raise exception 'magazine without pricing';
    end if;
    return null;
End;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER magazine_pricing_title_relation_on_magazine BEFORE update or insert on magazine 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_magazine_pricing_title_relation_on_magazine();
```

I'm then running:

```
INSERT INTO pricing VALUES ('dog', 4, 5);
```

and in the end I'm running:

```
INSERT INTO magazine VALUES('dog', 'james')
```

which gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  magazine without pricing
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function check_magazine_pricing_title_relation_on_magazine() line 6 at RAISE
```

Solving the problem would be ideal, but also giving me suggestions on how to simplify the code in another way would be also beneficial.

Comment: Make a Foreign Key from `magazine.title` to `pricing.title`.  This is essentially what you are doing with the trigger. As to error, did you do the Inserts in different sessions? Also you do not want to `RETURN NULL` on a `BEFORE` trigger as that will cause the operation to not fire. See [plpgsql trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html).

Comment: The cause of the error is that you created a statement level trigger instead of specifying `FOR EACH ROW`. @AdrianKlaver's suggestion of using a foreign key is essentially correct, but would require a change to the model since there isn't a unqiue key constraint on `pricing.title`.

Comment: Since `pricing`'s primary key is on '(title, period)', it appears that pricing should be referencing another table with `title` as a unique key and `period` as an occurence identifier. Triggers should not be required for enforcing referential integrity: use foreign keys instead.

Comment: @JohnH. More to the point I got the direction wrong . It would not work as originally described as `pricing` is the child table in that there could be many prices for a given title. The FK relationship would need to be `pricing.title` REFERENCES `magazine.title`.

Comment: I was asked in an assignment, to create a magazine table, and the task said that each magazine should have atleast one pricing, so if i would just create a foreign key in pricing, there is still a chance that a magazine would be left without a pricing.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger declaration must have the `FOR EACH ROW` clause for `NEW` to be populated with the new row values.

See CREATE TRIGGER in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

> FOR EACH ROW
> FOR EACH STATEMENT
>
> This specifies whether the trigger function should be fired once for every row affected by the trigger event, or just once per SQL
> statement. If neither is specified, **FOR EACH STATEMENT is the default**.
> Constraint triggers can only be specified FOR EACH ROW.

Also your function must return NEW, not NULL otherwise it cancels the insert, as the doc says:

> A row-level trigger fired before an operation has the following
> choices:
>
> It can return NULL to skip the operation for the current row. This instructs the executor to not perform the row-level operation that
> invoked the trigger (the insertion, modification, or deletion of a
> particular table row).

Also, note that trigger-based check of existence is not reliable in the presence on concurrent writes. The query in the trigger cannot see the changes that another session might have done and that have not been committed yet.